# How to support different iOS SDKs on Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

After installing Xcode 4.2 there is only iOS 5.0 SDK in Xcode.
Also I should support iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1.
How support two or more SDKs for one App with one Xcode?
I tried install Xcode 3 with iOS SDK 4.3 but Xcode crashes when starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest SDK included all required features from previous SDK versions. You shouldn't worry about it. If you want to support iPhone 3G just set **iOS Deployment Target** to iOS 4.2 (or another would you like) in project settings at *Build Settings* tab.

Don't remember to test your application on that iOS version.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try right now and I shall report the results.

Answer (score 5):

Set the deployment target of the App to iOS 4.2.1, this will allow all iOS devices running 4.2.1 or upwards to run your App, however, you won't get any compiler warnings if you use stuff from eg. 5.0, so double check your code and add branches if needed.
Another thing is that since Xcode 4.2, the compiler only generates armv7 code, but since you also want support for the iPhone 3G, you have to manually tell it to also generate `armv6` code by selecting your target, switching to the `Build Settings` Tab and there adding `armv6` to the `Architectures` list.

Comment: Everything works fine, thank you. Unfortunately I can't mark both answers as right answers, I marked first. But thank you anyway.